# My Ubuntu 16.04 doesn't have enable Wifi anymore4

Tags: 16.04, networking

I recently update my computer, a regular update, and when it restarted I noticed it wasn't connected to the wifi. I then tried to connect back and saw that the enable wifi option was completely gone. I am running Ubuntu 16.04 on a Dell Latitude 5480 laptop. I have no clue how to fix this issue, please help I use this for college and it has all of my files and work on it.

Comment: welcome to askubuntu. Can you please run the wireless-info-script and append its content to your question: https://askubuntu.com/a/425205/669014

Comment: Same exact issue popped up a day before you posted this for me on a Dell Precision 5520.  It was right after I ran the regular update also.